# How to secure different fiware GE in the same virtual machine?

Tags: fiware

I'm deploying some Generic Enablers(Orion, Cygnus, Proton-Cep, Wirecloud) in the same VM using dockers.

Reading the fiware documentation it uses has an example a wilma proxy securing an instance of orion and getting the authorization through IdM.

Wilma configurations do not seem to support different redirections

I need to secure all these services that I'm using which need to be accessed from outside the server, my question is if is it possible to use Wilma to secure all Generic Enablers or should I implement one instance of Wilma for each service provided?

Comment: Yes, you could use several Wilma instances. Other solution is to configure a proxy between wilma and the services to redirect the authenticated requests from wilma to the correct GE (basing on a path for instance)